# Converting XML node values to comma separated values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert XML node values to comma separated values but, getting a

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
>    error message

```
declare @dataCodes XML = '<Root>
                    <List Value="120" />
                    <List Value="110" />
                </Root>';

DECLARE   @ConcatString VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT   @ConcatString = COALESCE(@ConcatString + ', ', '') + Code FROM (SELECT T.Item.value('@Value[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') as Code  FROM  @dataCodes.nodes('/Root/List') AS T(Item))
SELECT   @ConcatString AS Result
GO
```

I tried to follow an [article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/converting-comma-separated-value-to-rows-and-vice-versa-in-sql-server.html) but not sure how to proceed further. Any suggestion is appreciated.

**Expectation:**

Comma separated values ('120,110') stored in a variable.

Comment: Of course you can use general-purpose languages like VB, C#, C++, Java, Python, PHP which excellently handles data conversion of flat files (xml, csv, txt, json, etc.) even results from RDMS connections. SQL is a special purpose language and should primarily be used to interact with databases (retrieval, manipulation, definition).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this;

```
DECLARE @dataCodes XML = '<Root>
                    <List Value="120" />
                    <List Value="110" />
                </Root>';      

DECLARE @ConcatString VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @ConcatString = COALESCE(@ConcatString + ', ', '') + Code
FROM (
    SELECT T.Item.value('@Value[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS Code
    FROM @dataCodes.nodes('/Root/List') AS T(Item)
    ) as TBL

SELECT @ConcatString AS Result
GO
```

You just need to add an alias to your sub SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, XML data can be extracted into arrays, lists, vectors, and variables for output in comma separated values more fluidly using general purpose languages. Below are open-source solutions using OP's needs taking advantage of `XPath`.

**Python**

```
import lxml.etree as ET

xml = '<Root>\
         <List Value="120" />\
         <List Value="110" />\
       </Root>'

dom = ET.fromstring(xml)
nodes = dom.xpath('//List/@Value')

data = []  # LIST
for elem in nodes:
    data.append(elem)

print((", ").join(data))

120, 110
```

**PHP**

```
$xml = '<Root>
         <List Value="120" />
         <List Value="110" />
       </Root>';

$dom = simplexml_load_string($xml);    
$node = $dom->xpath('//List/@Value');

$data = [];   # Array
foreach ($node as $n){  
     $data[] = $n; 
}

echo implode(", ", $data);

120, 110
```

**R**

```
library(XML)

xml = '<Root>
         <List Value="120" />
         <List Value="110" />
       </Root>'

doc<-xmlInternalTreeParse(xml)    
data <- xpathSApply(doc, "//List", xmlGetAttr, 'Value')  # LIST

print(paste(data, collapse = ', '))

120, 110
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this without a variable, you can use the `nodes` method to convert the xml nodes into a table format with leading commas, then use `FOR XML PATH('')` to collapse it into a single line of XML, then wrap that in `STUFF` to convert it to varchar and strip off the initial leading comma:

```
DECLARE @dataCodes XML = '<Root>
                <List Value="120" />
                <List Value="110" />
            </Root>';      
            
SELECT STUFF(
    (
    SELECT ', ' + T.Item.value('@Value[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
        FROM @dataCodes.nodes('/Root/List') AS T(Item)
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '')
```